# How do i access the "user" object in joomla

Tags: object, joomla

What i am trying to do is to output all user names from my joomla site. Actually i want to handle the user object. Any refference will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get object of current login user

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if(!$user->id){
  // no user is logged in
}
else{
  // logged in user
}
```

To get names of all users

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM #__users";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$users = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($users as $user){
  echo $user->name;
}
```

or if you want to use user object, after above query

```
foreach($users as $user){
   $userObj = JFactory::getUser($user->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the current user object you can find the details in here :

[Accessing the current user object - Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object)

If you want to list all the users I would recommend you check the extension called Community Builder, there's a plugin that list all the current website users for it

Answer (score 0):

```
$user =&JFactory::getUser();  
if($user->id) {    
    //do user logged in stuff    
}    
else {    
    //do user not logged in stuff    
}
```